# AIX - bash script

Tags: bash, websphere, aix

I'm trying to implement a small bash script in AIX, but I'm having some problems. Bellow you can find a example. I have another question, if I want to add the script to Crontab, I think I'll have problems to call serverStatus.sh from IBM, how can avoid this problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

WAS_HOME="/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/bpmnprd01/"

function StatusCheck()
{

$WAS_HOME/bin/serverStatus.sh BPM.AppTarget.bpmnprd01.0 -username admin -password admin
status=$(cat /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/bpmnprd01/logs/BPM.AppTarget.xxxxx/serverStatus.log| awk '{ if (NF > 0) { last = $NF } } END { print last }' "$@")
text="STOPPED"
if  [[ $text == $status ]]
    then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "NOK"
fi
}

function start()
{
StatusCheck
}
start
-----------------------
```

when I try to execute the script above, I get the following error:

```
[root@bpmnprd01]/root/health_check# ./servers_check.sh
./servers_check.sh[7]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 7 : `(' is not expected.
```

...after this I search on google, and I found some examples without "()" on subroutine.But I got this:

```
[root@bpmnprd01]/root/health_check# ./servers_check.sh
./servers_check.sh[30]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 33 : `StatusCheck' is not expected.
```

Thanks in Advance
Tiago

Answer (score 0):

AIX has a true bourne shell living in /bin/sh, not sure about /usr/bin/sh, but would expect that to be Bourne shell as well.

Change your script heading line (the #shebang!) to

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash
```

Or the result of `which bash`

IHTH

Comment: #!/usr/bin/sh is correct, the problem is other thing, thanks for your help. 
-r-xr-xr-x    5 bin      bin          292486 27 Mar 2012  sh

Comment: [root@bpmnprd01]/usr/bin# which sh
/usr/bin/sh

Comment: why do you tag your question and title with `bash`? A true `sh` cannot process `$(...cmd substitions)`, you'll need to use back-tick cmd substituion if you must use `#!/usr/bin/sh`. Good luck.

Comment: I made some changes, include your suggestion, I think never tried this without "()" in function call, now I'm getting this error:

ADMU0116I::  not found.

Comment: you obviously want to pursue your own solution to this problem, so good luck.

Comment: well :/
I don't know why a can't run this   `/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/bpmnprd01/bin/serverStatus.sh BPM.AppTarget.xxxxx -username admin -password admin`

Answer (score 0):

You are using bash specific syntax but calling the script with `sh`, which has more limited capabilities. Since you want to use `sh`, you can use a tool like `checkbashisms` or [`shellcheck`](http://www.shellcheck.net) to help uncover non-portable syntax.

The immediate problem is that `function foo() { ..; }` is not a POSIX compliant function definition, and you should drop the keyword `function` and use just `foo() { ..; }`.

Your shell may also be lacking `[[ ]]` in which case you should use `[ ]` instead, with `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: this is my problem now. I can't invoke this WAS system script: `/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/bpmnprd01/bin/serverStatus.sh BPM.AppTarget.xxxxx -username admin -password admin` inside script

Comment: well the problem was in status=$(cat line is too long for VI :/